Error 'Failed to load URL' using just_audio
I am developing on Flutter Web using just_audio.I have no problems with local builds, but when I run the app in Chrome and safari after deploying to Firebase hosting, I see the error 'Failed to load URL' in the following function in the developer tools.
  static Future<void> setSeMatch() async{
    try {
      AudioSource source =  AudioSource.asset('assets/se/match.mp3');
     await player.setAudioSource(source);

    } catch (e) {
      print('Error setSeMatch: $e');
    }
  }

I have also tried the following writing method, which according to the official documentation can also be used, but I am getting the same error.
  static Future<void> setSeMatch() async{
    try {
      await player.setAudioSource(
        AudioSource.uri(
          Uri.parse('asset:///se/match.mp3')), initialPosition: Duration.zero, preload: true);
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error setSeMatch: $e');
    }
  }

The load mp.3 file itself is successfully retrieved by the server. The problem is that the function that loads the mp3 file is failing. What is the problem?

